# Perl a cpan installation into a specific repository

Tags: perl, cpan

Hel lo, I'm actually installing a perl module called HmmCleaner here :

```
https://metacpan.org/pod/HmmCleaner.pl
```

for that I use :

```
/beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/bin/cpan Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner
```

But I'm actually into a shared cluster where we have 2 principal directories :

```
/beegfs/home/me
```

And

```
/beegfs/data/me
```

and in the home repository I have a threshold of number of chunk files  to not

I have a threshold that I cannot exceed of the number of chunk files and when I run the `/beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/bin/cpan Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner` command, for some reason some files are created into the home directory and when I look into the log file I see that something is wrong at this moment :

```
! Installing Bio::MUST::Core::Utils failed. See /beegfs/home/me/.cpanm/work/1580931498.36405/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
Warning: unable to close filehandle $out properly: Disk quota exceeded at /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/bin/cpanm line 49.
Warning: unable to close filehandle $out properly: Disk quota exceeded at /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/bin/cpanm line 49.
Warning: unable to close filehandle $out properly: Disk quota exceeded at /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/bin/cpanm line 49.
```

But when I look into the disk quota in `data`, both memory and chuck file limit is not reached, but for the `home` the number of chunk files is exceeded!

Does someone know how can I force to run all the files created in the installation into the data repository instead of home?

Thank you for your help.

for polarbear :

When I do :

```
/beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/bin/cpan -D local::lib
```

I get :
    Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging

```
CPAN.pm requires configuration, but most of it can be done automatically.
If you answer 'no' below, you will enter an interactive dialog for each
configuration option instead.

Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically? [yes] yes
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Reading '/beegfs/home/me/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Reading '/beegfs/home/me/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Thu, 06 Feb 2020 08:41:03 GMT
.............
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.27) available.
  [Currently running version is v2.22]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.


...............................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Reading '/beegfs/home/me/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
DONE
Writing /beegfs/home/me/.cpan/Metadata
local::lib
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (no description)
    H/HA/HAARG/local-lib-2.000024.tar.gz
    (no installation file)
    Installed: not installed
    CPAN:      2.000024  Not up to date
    Graham Knop (HAARG)
    haarg@haarg.org
```

Comment: *"...for some reason some files are created into the home directory.."* How do you know that? Which files are created in the home directory?

Comment: Because the number of chunk files increases when I install this module

Comment: It might be that it is due to the `cpanm` work directory is located at `/beegfs/home/me/`?

Answer (score 2):

Lets follow next scenario

```
mv ~/.cpam /beegfs/data/me
ln -s /beegfs/data/me/.cpan ~/.cpan
HOME=/beegfs/data/me perl -Mlocal::lib > ~/.lib_perl
```

these commands will

- move $HOME/.cpan directory from $HOME to /beegfs/data/me
- symlink it in $HOME directory
- run perl with local::lib module
- it will check for $SHELL
- output configuration variables to $HOME/.lib_perl file

Now source $HOME/.lib_perl in your shell environment according your $SHELL (bash - .bashrc, csh - .cshrc, ...) on login into system.

As you work remotely you have to logout and login to pickup changes (do it in separate terminal just in case if you do something wrong and you need *back door* to revert your changes).

At this point you should be able to use **cpan** to install modules into /beegfs/data/me/perl5 directory.

Comment: at the next step I get : Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (you may need to install the local::lib module) (@INC contains: /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/x86_64-linux /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/lib/site_perl/5.30.1 /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/lib/5.30.1/x86_64-linux /beegfs/data/met/perl-5.30.1/localperl/lib/5.30.1)

Comment: Check if you have $HOME/perl5 directory.

Comment: If you have this directory then try `HOME=/beegfs/data/me perl -I/beegfs/home/me/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib` -- it should pickup library from old place.

Comment: Aha, I've checked output of **cpan -D local::lib** -- it is not installed in your system. Then try `HOME=/beegfs/data/me cpan -i local::lib` to install it.

Comment: By specifying **HOME=/beegfs/data/me** you fool following command to believe that it is your **HOME** location and it should create **.cpan** and install **local::lib** (perl5 directory) in this location.

Comment: ok now a directory perl5 have been created at /beegfs/data/me with directory bin and lib (with bin empty)

Comment: Add source for generated file with variables into your shell login script (probably .bashrc) and attempt to login in new terminal window. On login verify that variables are set and attempt to install required module -- observe if it installed properly (it should). As variables set on login you can verify if perl uses them by issuing a command `perl -V`, check if **@INC** lists new location. Now write simple code which uses new module -- there should be no need to specify library as perl already aware where to look for modules (@INC serves this purpose).

Comment: I checked the INC and I get   INC:
    `/beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/x86_64-linux
    /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/lib/site_perl/5.30.1
    /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/lib/5.30.1/x86_64-linux
    /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/lib/5.30.1` but when I run `/beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/localperl/bin/cpan Bio::MUST::Apps::HmmCleaner` it still write on the `/beegfs/home/me/.cpan/`...

Comment: What is output of `env | grep -i perl`? Did you move ~/.cpan to /beegfs/data/me and symlink to it? If you did then files stored in /beegfs/data/me/.cpan and not in /beegfs/home/me/.cpan as it is a link.

Comment: when I do : `env | grep -i /beegfs/data/me/perl-5.30.1/perl`  I get nothing but with. `env | grep -I perl` I get : `OLDPWD=/beegfs/data/me/perl5`

Comment: You need second form of command and it does indicate that you did not set variables properly (you did not source your .local_perl on login. What is you level of experience with Linux/UNIX?

Answer (score 0):

Check if **local::lib** is installed with following command

cpan -D local::lib

If it is installed then head to following webpage [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) and do some reading - pay attention to point #4.

Otherwise check if [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm) is available in your system.

As an option you can set variables manually

```
PERL_MB_OPT
PERL_MM_OPT
PERL5LIB
PATH
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT
```

Before setting private *library* check that you have write permission on storage directory.

Comment: I edited my post with what you said, but it seems that local::lib is present here `/beegfs/home/me/.cpan/` in the `home` and I do not know why?

Comment: It is default location to store **cpan** catalogs and build directory (on my computer it takes about 100MB). **local::lib** uses directory with name **perl5** with default location at $HOME directory. Check quote on your home directory and see if some files can be removed. You can remove .cpan directory it will be recreated at next **cpan** run.

Comment: As work around of tight space you can create .cpan directory in /beegfs/data/me and symlink it to your home directory. Then run **cpan** and see if symlink will be preserved or removed.